# Jquery toggle div width on button click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

Hello I want to split my page display with divs.
Below is my html code.

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="divSectionInfo">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Toggle screen" class="btn" id="btnSlide">
        <div id="divProducts">                

        </div>
    </div>
```

div wrapper has 800 px
divSection has 300 px and divProducts has 400px.
I want to show divSectionInfo full width(800px)/half(300px) width based on the button toggle screen click.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `.toggleClass()` for your problem.

Here is the jQuery for it.

```
$('#btnSlide').on('click',function(){
$('#divSectionInfo').toggleClass('width800');
});
```

And create a css class called `width800` with following content.

```
.width800{
width: 800px !important;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle for the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/rison/epkdjmz5/

Comment: Hi Rison,
Thank u very much.
But my scenario is the divs are placed in single line horizontally.
So div product has to be hidden in order to display divsection with width 800px.
I hpe U know what I mean..

Comment: @sandeep.mishra In that case, add `$('#divProducts').toggle();` inside the `click` function. Here is the updated jsFiddle to help you out [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rison/epkdjmz5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, check with jQuery what the current width is and set the width to the other value.

```
$("#btnSlide").on("click", function(){
    var div = $("#divSectionInfo");
    var width = (div.width() === 800 ) ? "300" : "800";
    div.css("width", width);
});
```

[JSfiddle with working example](http://jsfiddle.net/u8yysuoe/)

- This checks if the button is clicked
- Saves the div to a variable (for better performance)
- Checks if the width equals 800: 
  true - set the var width to 300 
  false - set var width to 800
- Set the CSS of the div to the width variable